# Extracting decimal points in C++

Tags: c++

how do I extract decimal points from a floating number because I already used modulus and it's giving me an error...like take out the 0.6 from 3.6 in C++

Comment: Looks like you are looking into [std::trunc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us, and describe your problems with it.

Comment: Please post what you tried and indicate where you are running into problems.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator `%` is defined only for integers.

The standard way of doing this would be to use [`std::modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf).

Or, you could more-or-less do it yourself by computing `x - std::floor(x)`.

Comment: It's not clear what the OP would like to see when there is a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way this can be done is casting the floating point types to int types and then subtracting the int returned value from the original float value. Like so...

```
float f = 3.6;
double d = 445.2323442;

float fExtractDecimals = f - int(f);
double dExtractDecimals = d - long(d);

std::cout << fExtractDecimals << " and ";
std::cout << dExtractDecimals << std::endl;
```

**Output**

> 0.6 and 0.2323442

Comment: It's not clear what the OP would like to see when `f` and `d` are negative numbers.